# What type of ordering is it

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $A\subseteq^*B\iff A$ \ $B$ is finite (For $A,B,\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$) i think i have might have written the question down incorrectly, i was wondering if someone can clarify should it be "(For $A,B\in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$)" and how would i start to establish if $\subseteq^*$ is a partial ordering or a total ordering, would i go back to the definition of what $A$ \ $B$ is and go from there?

My attempt so far is the following: First recall that $A\setminus B=\{x\in A:x\notin B\}$, Now Let $B=\{x,y\}$ and let $A=\{x,y,z\}$  where $x,y,z \in \Bbb N$.Then clearly $A\setminus B=\{z\}$ which is finite and since $z\in \Bbb N$ then clearly $\{z\}\in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ then clearly $z\in A$ and so the reflexive property holds?. (i'm not sure my approach is correct any clarification of this would be great, i don't see any point in checking the other two properties are correct if my approach to the first property is incorrect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it says $A,B\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ it just means that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

To show that a relation is a partial order, you must show that it satisfies reflexivity, anti-symmetry, and transitivity. It sounds like you don't really understand what reflexivity means based on your attempt. A relation $R$ is reflexive iff $\forall x,xRx$. In your example, you need to show that for every set $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, $A\subseteq^* A$. This should be easy because $A\setminus A=\emptyset$, which is finite.

To show that a partial order relation $R$ is a total order, you must show that for all $A$ and $B$, either $ARB$ or $BRA$. To show that it isn't a total order, find a counterexample.

As was resolved in the comments below, $\subseteq^*$ isn't even a partial order because it doesn't satisfy antisymmetry. A counterexample is $\{1\} $ and $\{2\} $.

Comment: Hi thanks for this I should have been clearer, I know how to show that $\subseteq$ is a total ordering on things like ($\Bbb N,\subseteq$) but I'm unsure how to approach it with the if and only if statement in this particular problem, this answer doesn't really help as is but thank you

Comment: @Gibberish $\subseteq$ is not a partial order on $\mathbb{N}$, because it it doesn't even make sense to say, for instance, $2\subseteq 3$. Did you mean $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$? Even then it's only a partial order, not a total order.

Comment: @Gibberish What do you mean the "if and only if statement" is confusing you? Are you referring to the definition of $\subseteq^*$?

Comment: yes, it's confusing me because the examples I've done are just usual operations such as $\le$ and $\in$  for example the previous one was to determine what type of ordering $\le$ has on the $\Bbb R$

Comment: @Gibberish What's confusing you about it? The $\iff$ only serves to provide a definition of $\subseteq^*$ in your case.

Comment: I've just read your updated post, it makes sense now thank you!

Comment: Does the anti-symmetric case fail, since if $A\subseteq^*B$ and $B\subseteq^*A$ then $A=B$ but since $A\subseteq^*B\iff A\setminus B$ finite, how can A and B be equal if $A\setminus B$ is finite as this would imply that A has an element that B does not, so surely by this logic $A\ne B$ unless A and B are already assumed to have the same elements ?

Comment: @Gibberish you're right that it fails antisymmetry, but you're reasoning is wrong. $A\setminus B $ is finite does not imply that $A$ has an element not in $B$. Remember that the empty set is finite.

Comment: okay so how would i go futher from this, thats the only reason i thought it was failing. would i need to do it in two different cases one when $A,B$ have the same elements and one when $A,B$ are different?

Comment: @Gibberish Just show a counterexample. For example, antisymmetry fails for $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$

Comment: is this because $A\setminus B$ does not exist ?

Comment: @Gibberish No. $A\setminus B$ is defined for any sets $A$ and $B$. The reason antisymmetry fails is seen by applying its definition. We know that $\{1\}\subseteq^*\{2\}$ because $\{1\}\setminus \{2\}=\{1\}$, which is finite. And we know that $\{2\}\subseteq^*\{1\}$ because $\{2\}\setminus \{1\}=\{2\}$, which is finite. From this, antisymmetry dictates that $\{1\}=\{2\}$. But this is obviously false, so antisymmetry fails.